# Keycloak: Restrict max users in a realm

Tags: keycloak

Is there a configuration to restrict maximum users in a realm?

Let's say I want to restrict maximum users in keycloak to 500. Is this possible?

To elaborate on my need, let's say I have configured ldap. Now every time an Ldap user logs in the keycloak, same user gets created in keycloak db. Now I want to restrict maximum such users to be 500. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create your custom Federation Provider, you can use LDAP provider as base and rewrite some methods (`getUserByEmail`, `getUserById`, `getUserByEmail`) for you logic implementation.